# "For" fails but "loop" works

Tags: clojure

I want to execute some SQL statements using SQLKorma. At first I wrote the following code:

```
(let [sqls (-> (slurp "resources/database.sql")
              (str/split #";")
              butlast)]
  (for [sql sqls]
      (k/exec-raw sql)))
```

But for reasons unknown, this does not work. The for loop gets skipped completely. This however works:

```
(let [sqls (-> (slurp "resources/database.sql")
              (str/split #";")
              butlast)]
  (loop [sqls sqls]
    (if (not (empty? sqls))
      (do
        (k/exec-raw (first sqls))
        (recur (rest sqls))))))
```

Why does this happen? Why does the for loop fail?

Comment: In Clojure `for` is not a loop, it's list comprehension. Don't let the name fool you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` creates a lazy sequence. Clojure executes each element of the lazy sequence only when you actually use it somehow. If you need only side effects you should force the execution of the lazy sequence with [`dorun`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/dorun).

In your case I'd recommend you to use `map`

```
(->> (str/split (slurp "resources/database.sql")
                #";")
     butlast
     (map k/exec-raw)
     dorun)
```

or `doseq` ([see mtyaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522682/for-fails-but-loop-works/17522777#17522777)) instead of `for` loop

```
(doseq [sql (-> (slurp "resources/database.sql")
                (str/split #";")
                butlast)]
  (k/exec-raw sql))
```

I like `map` version more, however`doseq` works a little bit faster.

Comment: map is lazy just like for is; mapv is not lazy

Comment: Yes, it's why there is a `dorun` in my example.

Comment: I added `doseq` example based on mtyaka's answer.

Answer (score 8):

`for` is lazy. Use `doseq` instead:

```
(doseq [sql sqls]
  (k/exec-raw sql))
```